# Setting the active executable in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have just updated to Xcode 3.2 Beta 3. Since doing this - the project I am working on only has one option in the drop-down box in the top-left corner for 'Active Executable' that is set for 'iPad Simulator (3.2)'.

I am developing for the iPhone and have no interest in the iPad. How can I get the iPhone to appear as an active executable so I can carry on developing for it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Hold down the option key while clicking on the drop down menu.