# Setting the active executable in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, ipad

I have the same problem as this guy had :
[Setting the active executable in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332214/setting-the-active-executable-in-xcode)

I'm pressing the "option" key, and it does add more options, i'm choosing iphone simulator 3.1.3 , but when I press "run" , still the ipad simulator is running.

The problem only appears when I choose "Iphoe simulator 3.2" as my active SDK.
If I choose "Iphone simulator 3.1.3" as my active SDK , there is no problem at all.

So I wonder, does 3.2 sdk is only for ipad development ? Is there any iphone 3.2 simulator at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sdk 3.2 is only for ipad, it can be used for iphone, I believe, but there is nothing new for iphone from 3.1.3 to 3.2

Answer (score 1):

3.2 is the base OS for the ipad. If you work in the new xcode 3.2.3 you will find only two options in the list available 3.2 and 4.0 Ipad and Iphone. The reason 3.2 is available for an iphone build is because of the ipads ability to run iphone apps and then x2 them in size.

If you build an ipad app 3.2 is your only OS at this current period to worry about.