# How to change the default Xcode iphone simulator when testing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I don't know why but now the default iphone simulator launched when I build the project is "ipad", but I want it to use iphone 3g instead.

Any way to set this preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me works changing active SDK from 3.2 to 4.0. If your project is mentioned to work on iPad  and iPhone (or for compatibility matters) I believe the only way is manually switching active executable before running your app on simulator.
Apple:"iPhone OS 3.2 does not support iPhone and iPod touch devices. It runs only on iPad.".

Comment: may be this helps too. It works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332214/setting-the-active-executable-in-xcode

Answer (score 55):

On Mac, if you right click on the Simulator icon, you can select devices and it will open a new device.[image]

Or go to File -> Open Simulator

Answer (score 21):

In Xcode,

Click Product -> Destination -> iOS Simulator -> Choose Device to run.

Then build and execute Xcode project.

It works..

Answer (score 12):

**2022 Fix:**

You have two options!

1. With the simulator running go to `File > Open Simulator > iOS [current version]` and select the desired device.
2. With the simulator running, right click the icon in the bottom toolbar, select `Device > iOS [current version]` and select the desired device

If you are using [Expo](https://expo.dev/), after selecting the new device will open in a new window, so you'll have both. Heres how to get Expo to run on the new device:

1. Close the device window you don't want (`cmd + w`)
2. You will now be able to "Run on iOS Simulator" and it will open up Expo Go on the new device.

**2020 Fix:**

1. With the simulator running go to `File > Open Device > iOS > iPhone 11` and select the device. It will open up the device as another window but there won't be the Expo app.
2. Close the device window you don't want (`cmd + w`), then close the window with the device you would like.
3. Restart Expo (in the command window with it running do `ctrl + c` then re-run Expo with `expo start`
4. You will now be able to "Run on iOS Simulator" and it will open up with the selected device type.

Comment: i didn't understand the 3th point. you should start excode using terminal then quit it and start it again??

Answer (score 8):

In the chance that anyone reading this is building their app in react-native, the solution is the --simulator option.

For example:

```
$ react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone X"
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you have given a solution which doesn't require to build the project again and again.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Hardware > Device from simulator menu.

Answer (score 3):

You can select the device from the menu inthe simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Try 
Project > Active Executable , and select the one you want the most.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me, but the following took care of the issue :

**Source:**
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/301182-xcode-3-2-6-keeps-switching-to-ipad-simulator.html

**Excerpt:**

> This works for Xcode 3.2.6.  I don't yet use Xcode 4.x so don't know
> if this will work for it or not.  I would also quit Xcode before doing
> this, just in case.
>
> Go to the project folder and find the .xcodeproj file.  Right-click
> (or Control-click) it and select Show Package Contents.  When the
> package contents window appears, find the .pbxuser file (there might
> be multiple such files if the project was worked on by multiple folks
> and/or multiple computers). Open this file, which is XML, in your
> preferred text editor. Find the section with the comment "/* Project
> object */". There is most likely not a line in that section for the
> key "activeSDKPreference".  If there is no such key, add the
> following:
>
> activeSDKPreference = iphonesimulator4.2;
>
> I found it after the "activeExecutable" key in that section, so I've
> been adding it in that same order.
>
> If there is already an "activeSDKPreference" entry, change it to
> "iphonesimulator4.2".
>
> Close the editor and the package contents window and then double click
> the .xcodeproj file to reopen the project.  Now you should have
> entries for iPhone Simulator 4.2 and iPad Simulator 4.2 in the project
> settings pull down menu, with iPhone Simulator 4.2 probably already
> checked.

***Additional Notes:***

> 1. In my particular case, my entry in .pbxuser file had said
>    iphonesimulator4.3, even though under Project-Project Settings
>    menu
>    it said iphonesimulaor4.2!.  However, once I changed it to
>    iphonesimulator4.2 in the .pbxuser file it stop auto selecting
>    iPad
>    all the time.

> 2. If you use SVN you will not see an "M" in SVN column showing that
>    you changed the project (even if you refresh/update). However,
>    just
>    do a "Commit Entire Project" and your changes to .pbxuser file
>    will
>    get updated.  I also suggest referencing this post in your
>    check-in
>    comment in case you ever need to change it back for whatever
>    reason.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. When I already have the app open on an iphone in "Simulator". I click File -> Open Simulator -> iOS 14.0 -> iPhone 8 (or iPad (7th generation))

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem myself.

First, install new version of Xcode, which is Xcode 4.

Then set project scheme to iPhone Simulator and run app in Xcode several times.

And re-install Xcode 3 and the problem will be gone!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's annoying. This worked for me:
Open the .plist file in group/folder resources and check the checkbox for key "Application requires iPhone environment".

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode Version 3.2.6 the following helps:
Project->Active Executable->iPhone Simulator 4.3

I don't know if it is working for newer Xcode environments.
Gary Tsui has also pointed out this approach previously.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flutter, open the `Runner.xcodeproj` file in `ios/` folder. Then right next to the `Runner` breadcrumb, you can click `>`and select what device to launch.