# How to change the default Xcode iphone simulator when testing in the terminal?

Tags: xcode, react-native, terminal, ios-simulator

I know there is a simular question here:
([How to change the default Xcode iphone simulator when testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643298/how-to-change-the-default-xcode-iphone-simulator-when-testing)) 
But it still doesn't answer the question of how to do it in the terminal.

Meaning: I'm working on a React Native project now & when I run it in the terminal (react-native run-ios) it opens iPhone 6. Now I would like to change this default to a iPhone 7 as it works better on my screen. How can I change this. (I've tried changing it in Xcode, but It keeps changing back.)

I have looked through All similar questions, and haven't found a straight forward answer. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can provide your preferred simulator in the command as:

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone5"`

You can check the available simulators by running this command from the terminal:

`xcrun simctl list devices`

Answer (score 2):

you set in Package.json in the terminal runtime you Hit these like  **`yarn ios-max`**

```
"scripts": {
    "reinstall": "rm -rf node_modules; yarn cache clean; yarn install",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "ios-min": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 5s'",
    "ios-mid": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 8 Plus'",
    "ios-max": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone X'",
    "ipad": "react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPad Air'",
    "ios-device": "react-native run-ios --device",
    "android-min": "react-native run-android",
    "android-max": "react-native run-android",
    "android-release": "react-native run-android --variant=release",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simulator -> Hardware -> Device iOS 11.1 -> click one as default

Answer (score 0):

the best and the easiest way to change iOS device is :
1- open simulator [image]
2- choose file > open simulator > then choose the device you want