# How to run specific iPhone version with create-react-native-app?

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

Based on [How to change the default Xcode iphone simulator when testing in the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077128/how-to-change-the-default-xcode-iphone-simulator-when-testing-in-the-terminal), I'd expect something like `yarn run ios --simulator="iPhone 8"` to work but it doesn't.

I'm using `"react-native-scripts": "1.5.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

As says in documentation for [exp Command Line Interface](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/exp-cli.html);

> -i, --ios              Opens your app in Expo in a currently running iOS simulator on your computer

So basically you can start your desired simulator before running it with expo and expo will detect the currently running simulator and then deploy your code.

Comment: thanks! i guess there is no way to specify it from the command line then? i'm writing a readme for my team and would prefer one-step "run this command" vs "open the simulator, pick a device, then run this command".

Comment: Command line interface has couple of commands and they have options. Check them out maybe there is a way to give device name